# PostgreSQL восстановление схемы из backup

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, резервное-копирование

Столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо сначала забэкапить, а затем восстановить из бекапа одну из схем базы данных в Posgresql 9.3.9.

Бэкап совершаю следующей командой:

```
pg_dump business_card_base --schema test > /tmp/test.backup
```

Обратно пытался восстановить и

```
pg_dump business_card_base < /tmp/test.backup
```

и

```
pg_dump business_card_base --schema test < /tmp/test.backup
```

схема остаётся пустой.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pg_dump` только делает дамп базы данных, а восстановлением этих данных не занимается. Посмотрите в свой файл `/tmp/test.backup`, там SQL-код. Чтобы осуществить восстановление, этот код просто нужно выполнить, например так:

```
 $ psql -f /tmp/test.backup business_card_base
```